# Does Click support "bunching" short options together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

Certain command line tools allow "bunching" of short options.

For example, the `tar` command takes short options `-x`, `-v`, and `-f` *filespec.* It allows the options to be bunched together like `-xvf` *filespec* to avoid the redundant typing of space-dash.

Reading the [documentation for Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#boolean-flags) I cannot find any indication if this is supported or not.

The documentation does say that alternative prefix characters (like `+w/-w`) are supported, which tends to suggest that perhaps it is not supported.

So:

1. Does `click` support bunching together short options?
2. If so, is this automatic, or does it need to be configured?
3. What is the search keyword I should use to find documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click definitely supports stacking short flag options.  Not sure that is it necessarily
documented in the click docs, but this is a standard POSIX command line convention as
documented [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).  The second bullet point of [why to use Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/why/) states:

- supports implementation of Unix/POSIX command line conventions

#### Test code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-x', is_flag=True)
@click.option('-y', is_flag=True)
@click.option('-z')
def cli(x, y, z):
    click.echo(f'x:{x}  y:{y}  z:{z}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '-x',
        '-y',
        '-z 1',
        '-xz 2',
        '-yz 3',
        '-xyz 4',
        '-yx',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 7.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> -x
x:True  y:False  z:None
-----------
> -y
x:False  y:True  z:None
-----------
> -z 1
x:False  y:False  z:1
-----------
> -xz 2
x:True  y:False  z:2
-----------
> -yz 3
x:False  y:True  z:3
-----------
> -xyz 4
x:True  y:True  z:4
-----------
> -yx
x:True  y:True  z:None
-----------
> --help
Usage: test_code.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -x
  -y
  -z TEXT
  --help   Show this message and exit.
```